# Contacts are not synchronised for iPad

Tags: ipad, data-synchronization, contacts

I have MBP (2013 Model), iPhone XS Max and iPad Pro 10.5 (2017) and all of them are running the latest operating systems versions. The iPad is a WiFi model (no 3G)

I got a phone call while I was reading on iPad. The phone call was only a number with no name. I searched my contacts on iPhone and it is from my clinic (the number and the name is saved but the iPad didn't show the name). I opened "Contacts" app on iPad and it missing a lot of contacts that I have shared between my devices.

I went to settings and toggled iCloud contacts syncing on and off but the same, some contacts are missing.

What could be the issue?

Comment: Was that contact already synched to iCloud? You can check that via iCloud.com. You may also want to check if you have the same number of contacts stored on your iPhone, MBP, and iPad locally. You can see the number of contacts stored locally by going to the end of contacts in any of these devices. On iCloud.com, select all contacts in the contacts section to see the number of contacts stored on iCloud.